# TypeORM Recursive Entities

Tags: database, typescript, recursion, orm, typeorm

So I have 2 entities `Item` & `Group`

An `Item` can have multiple "sub groups"

A `Group` can have multiple "sub items"

I need to create this recursive relationship in TypeORM but I'm unsure how to do it properly.
I assume I need a ManyToMany but not sure where the `JoinTable()` goes.
I've tried the following and it doesn't seem work right when adding an `Item` to a `Group`

Another point is that this tree is recursive. There is no limit to the depth of this tree and one `Item` can belong to many `Groups` and a `Group` can belong to many `Items`

```
class Item {
   {...}

   @ManyToMany(type => Group, group => group.items)
   @JoinTable()
   groups: Group[];
}

class Group {
   {...}
   
   @ManyToMany(type => Item, item => item.groups)
   @JoinTable()
   items: Item[];
}
```

Comment: According to Typeorm, @JoinTable must be only on one side of the relation (doesn't matter which entity).

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md
check bi-directional relations section.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `@JoinTable()` from one the entities:

```js
class Item {
   {...}

   @ManyToMany(type => Group, group => group.items)
   groups: Group[];
}
```

```js
class Group {
   {...}
   
   @ManyToMany(type => Item, item => item.groups)
   @JoinTable()
   items: Item[];
}
```